# How to fix a program to work with Pytest? It works fine when run manually

Tags: python, pytest

I have a query on pytest. I have a program that works fine when I run it on terminal:

```
"python ./solution/program1.py ./data/set.data 15 123 output-1.txt"
```

Here

```
program1.py - program name
set.data    - input data set
15          -  input program parameter
123         - input program parameter
output-1.txt- output file
```

The output file is generated for the program.

I have a pytest that checks my results. This doesn't work with pytest. 
When I run pytest, there is no output, the pytest keeps on running without any results. I have to manually stop it. Is there any way I could fix it?

Pytest:

```
import subprocess, os

def test_kmeans():
    file_name = "output-1.txt"
    command="python ./solution/program1.py ./data/set.data 15 123 {}".format(file_name)
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    code=process.wait()
    assert(not code), "Command failed"
    assert(open(file_name,"r").read()==open("tests/final-results.txt","r").read())
```

Comment: Is this a current working directory issue where the `subprocess.Popen` opens in an OS directory instead of the directory you are expecting?

Comment: Well, the issue is because of the program not being optimized

Comment: Try specifying the absolute path instead of a relative path in the call from the test.